# How to improve security of an online form that do not require a login?

Tags: html, forms, security

I have an online form that is sent to our suppliers by our contract department. This form allows our suppliers to update their company information and product prices.

We do not want to force them to use a login since we don't want to create an account for all our suppliers, and this is something that they will do once a year, so they will most likely forget their credentials.

This online form does display some sensitive information since it will display the current "broker" price.

I was thinking of creating a unique URL that will be sent to them through email. But I have to make sure that

- Only the intended recipient is able to read and update the form
- Reduce the risk of URL forgery that would allow someone to open a bunch of form by guessing the other unique URL.

This URL will be sent by email and we expect the supplier to click and edit the form. In the email, I was gonna include a numeric password that must be used when posting the updated information and each URL would have an expiration.

What are the best practice in generating such unique URL and what step could be used to increase the security to prevent the risk listed above?

Comment: This might get some good answers at Security.StackExchange.com as well as here.  I bet we'll have some good ideas from this site, but over there, they may offer alternative approaches we wouldn't think of.  I know for me, personally, as a developer, the answer to every program is "write a program to handle it".  It limits the ideas I come up with, so some alternative perspective might be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

generate a random string for each customer like `GJAOEJGOMASDIG2351DSFGSD` and put that somewhere in the URL. When they access the URL - make sure the random string matches the company's random string...?

`http://www.domain.com/form.php?customerId=255&rand=GJAOEJGOMASDIG2351DSFGSD`

```
$sql = "Select * from customers where id=".$custId." and randomHash='".$randString."'";
```

This way, viewers need to know the customer's ID and their matching random string. If either do not match, deny access.

make sure to take precautions against SQL Injection.

Comment: This is good!  I'd add to this to have the random url be a one-time use item, with a time limit. (Must be used by x days from now, can only be used once, and then is marked as expired)

Comment: Yes... when you do the check, you can (once verified) set the customer's random string to NULL to prevent future retrievals if desired. This random string can also be stored in a separate table with all sorts of data about that string. Expiration Date, Max Number of Uses, etc..

Comment: Make sure you generate the random string in a secure manner. i.e. don't use a random number generator with a predictable seed.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious answer is:

Add to the URL a parameter with a random number, large number (store in a DB which numbers have been assigned, and to which email)

When the user clicks the URL, he must put the right email in the form.